# WebRequest.GetResponse().....What happened to it?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

OK I've been playing with Silverlight and ran into something interesting that I hope someone can explain.  The MSDN documentation clearly states that it has a WebRequest.GetResponse() Method.  I have created some code to get the latest messages from twitter.  The code works fine in a console app but I get an error when its in a silverlight app.  The code is exactly the same, but in my xaml.cs file, the method seems to have disappeared from the framework.  Anyone know why?  Here are two screen shots showing you what I mean.

Console App: http://twitpic.com/bl6cf

Silverlight: http://twitpic.com/bl6ev

Comment: Does GetResponse appear as part of intellisense in the silverlight version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight Documentation does not list GetResponse() method because, In Silverlight you can call only BeginGetResponse method.

This is because you may block the UI thread and that may block the browser. BeginGetResponse is an asynchronous method.

Comment: I thought it could be due to client making a request from Browser but didn't know of the blocking thing. +1

Comment: On the other hand, how is the compiler blocking the method from being called? Is it a separate assembly (scaled down version) for silverlight?

Comment: Yes, infact entire Silverlight Library is compiled with an attribute "SILVERLIGHT", you can check it in properties of your project.

Silverlight libraries are scaled down version, but I think they are completely rewritten for modified silverlight CLR.

And yes compiler and your visual studio does read "SILVERLIGHT" attribute and loads assembly accordingly.